# How to find combinations of multidimensional array in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[
    [1],
    [2, 22],
    [3, 33, 333],
    [4]
]
```

I want to turn it into the following array:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 33, 4],
    [1, 2, 333, 4],
    [1, 22, 3, 4],
    [1, 22, 33, 4],
    [1, 22, 333, 4],
]
```

The order of the numbers in each sub-array matters, but the order of the sub-arrays within the big one doesn't. 1 must always come before 2, and so on. I'm using numbers to simplify but they will be **strings**, so I can't use math for this.

---

Edit: A simple version of the above would be the following:

```
// the following:
[
    [1],
    [2, 22],
]
// would be converted to:
[
    [1, 2],
    [1, 22]
]
```

Comment: Fixed the main example. If it's not right then use the simpler example.

Comment: Can you share what _you have tried_?

Comment: @maxshuty This is what I have been trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/yaharga/uega8ns7/90/ It's messy since I'm still working on it but I tried to search to find something along the lines of lodash or searching for "multidimensional array combinations" and found nothing.